# If $A\subseteq B$ and $A$ is countably infinite and $B$ is uncountable, then $B\setminus A$ is uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- Prove or disprove:If $A\subseteq B$ and $A$ is countably infinite and $B$ is uncountable, then $B\setminus A$ is uncountable.

Then there is a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ and there is no bijection between $B$ and $\mathbb{N}$? Also, clearly there is no bijection between $B\setminus A$ and $\mathbb{N}$? But how can I show this, can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Sketch: Suppose, for contradiction, that $B\setminus A$ were countable.  Then, there would be a surjective map from $\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$ to $B$, i.e., $(n,0)\rightarrow A$ and $(n,1)\rightarrow B\setminus A$.  Since $\mathbb{N}\times\{0,1\}$ is countable, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

Assume $B$ \ $A$ is countable:

$A$ is countable:

$A = ${ $a_1,a_2,....a_k,...$}.

$B$ \ $A$ is countable:

$B$ \ $A= ${ $b_1,b_2,....,b_k,...$}.

$B = A \cup (B$ \ $A) =$

{ $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,......a_k,b_k,.....$}.

Bijective $f:$

$f$: $B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$..

$f(x)= 2(k-1)$ for $x=a_k$, $k=1,2,3,...$

$f(x)= 2(k-1)+1$ for $x =b_k$, $k=1,2,3,..$

A contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$B = (B \setminus A) \cup A$.

$A$ is given to be countable.

If $B \setminus A$ were also countable their union, $B$, would be countable too, which it is not. So $B \setminus A$ is uncountable.